# jQuery/Javascript Multiple Array Combinations

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to find a solution to this with no avail. The idea of what i'm trying to achieve is to be able to find all unique combinations of multiple lists. So, let's say I have 3 lists of checkboxes (but this is an unknown number in the real-life application), Colour, Size, Pack Size. The items in the list's will be unqiue.

```
[0] => ['blue', 'green']
[1] => ['small', 'medium', 'large']
[2] => ['Pack Of 6', 'Pack Of 8']
```

I will want to get "**Blue, Small, Pack Of 6**", "**Blue, Medium, Pack Of 6**", "**Blue, Large, Pack Of 6**", "**Blue, Small, Pack Of 8**", "**Blue, Medium, Pack Of 8**" etc..
The ordering isn't important, but would be nice to have it logically grouped.

I already have the lists pulled out into an array using jQuery:

```
       options = [];

       jQuery('.option-types').each(function(){
            opts = [];
            jQuery('input:checked', this).each(function(){
                opts.push(jQuery(this).next().text());
            });
            options.push(opts)
        });
```

If there is a recursive functional path to answer this that would be ideal, as like i said the number of lists could be anything, aswell as the contents of the lists.

Hope you guys and girls can help, this is doing my head in.

Cheers - Dan

Comment: If i can get the output to be an array for each one that would be great - so [0] = ["Small", "Blue", "Pack Of 6"], [1] = ["Small, "Green", "Pack Of 8"], etc..

Comment: Sry I don't get your question - I see what you have so far but what do you want?

Comment: I mentioned above and below the first code block, to get the unqiue combinations of all the items

Comment: I have found the following link which might do the job, but it's in python. If anyone can help just translate it that would be great! Thanks - http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496807/

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/9422386/405017 for a 'lazy' (deferred) JavaScript version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work :)

```
var recursiveSearch;
var possibilities = [];

recursiveSearch = function (text, depth )
{
 text = text || "";
 depth = depth || 0;
 for ( var i = 0; i < options[depth].length; i++ )
 {
   // is there one more layer?
   if ( depth +1 < options.length )
     // yes: iterate the layer
     recursiveSearch ( text + ((text=="") ? "" : " ") + options[depth][i] , depth +1 );
   else
     // no: this is the last layer. we add the result to the array
     possibilities.push ( text + options[depth][i] );
 }
}


recursiveSearch ( );
```

with your array

```
[0] => ['blue', 'green']
[1] => ['small', 'medium', 'large']
[2] => ['Pack Of 6', 'Pack Of 8']
```

the result would be sth like this:

1. blue small pack of 6
2. blue small pack of 8
3. blue medium pack of 6
4. ...

Comment: Ghommey, you are bang on it. Thanks ever so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the Java source code from page http://www.1your.com/drupal/FullCodeFindingAllStringCombinationsUsingRecursion to JavaScript - the idea should be easy to understand, even if you have not much exposure to Java. I doubt there is a ready-made solution to this.

Comment: I can't really see how that is relevant to this problem as this is dealing with multiple 2D arrays, thanks though.